# AttributeError: type object 'frame1' has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, python-requests

¡Hola! ¿Qué tal, como les va? Espero que bien. Soy yo de nuevo...

Esta vez vengo con un AttriubteError. Les comento: estoy haciendo un GUI con tkinter en el que he dividido los frames en un modulo y el contenido en otro (no se que tan correcto sea pero me resulta mas fácil trabajarlo así).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label
import framesayuda

framesayuda.AppSimple()

#Aqui se encuentran la pantalla de inicio del programa.
tituloPrograma= Label(framesayuda.frame1, text= "PROGRAMA DE EJEMPLO")
tituloPrograma.pack()
textoPrograma= Label(framesayuda.frame1, text= "El siguiente programa es una DEMO para observar la funcionalidad de los Frames. ").pack()

botonSiguiente1= tk.Button(framesayuda.frame1, text= "INICIO", command=lambda: framesayuda.mostrarFrame(framesayuda.frame2))
botonSiguiente1.pack()

#Contenido de la segunda pantalla.
tituloPrograma2= Label(framesayuda.frame2, text= "PROGRAMA DE EJEMPLO")
tituloPrograma2.pack()
textoPrograma2= Label(framesayuda.frame2, text= "El siguiente programa es una DEMO para observar la funcionalidad de los Frames. ").pack()

botonSiguiente2= tk.Button(framesayuda.frame2, text= "SIGUIENTE", command=lambda: framesayuda.mostrarFrame(framesayuda.frame1))
botonSiguiente2.pack()
```

Como pueden ver tengo unos labels en un frame llamado frame1 y estos en un modulo llamado framesayuda, que es asi:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import mainloop
    
class AppSimple(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.mostrarFrame(frame1)

    def mostrarFrame(self, frameClass):
        nuevoFrame = frameClass(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = nuevoFrame
        self._frame.pack()

class frame1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

class frame2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

El problema viene que cuando ejecuto el programa me arroja el AtributteError y la verdad es que no tengo idea de como solucionarlo. Se que el problema esta en el modulo framesayuda.

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

De antemano, **muchas gracias.**

Comment: `framesayuda.frame1` no existe. Tu clase AppSimple no tiene ningún atributo "frame1", si no guardas referencias a las variables en la clase no puedes acceder luego a ellas, porque obviamente no existen

Comment: Oh, no entiendo. ¿Cómo le hago para guardar la referencia a la variable en la clase? y hacer que exista.

Bueno, pero el problema no dice que sea con la clase AppSimple si no con la clase frame1 y que este no tiene el atributo tk, supongo que el atributo lo debería heredar de la clase AppSimple pero eso ya lo esta haciendo al poner tk.Frame ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo de nuevo...

Al final tras leer mucho el código llegue a una solución, sinceramente no es la solución que quería pero el funciona como lo deseaba.

Por si ha alguien le sirve, lo hice así:

```
import tkinter as tk
    
class AppSimple(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.mostrarFrame(frame1)

    def mostrarFrame(self, frameClass):
        nuevoFrame = frameClass(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = nuevoFrame
        self._frame.pack()

class frame1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tituloPrograma= tk.Label(self, text= "PROGRAMA DE EJEMPLO")
        tituloPrograma.pack()
        textoPrograma= tk.Label(self, text= "El siguiente programa es una DEMO para observar la funcionalidad de los Frames. ").pack()

        botonSiguiente1= tk.Button(self, text= "INICIO", command=lambda: master.mostrarFrame(frame2))
        botonSiguiente1.pack()

class frame2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tituloPrograma2= tk.Label(self, text= "PROGRAMA DE EJEMPLO")
        tituloPrograma2.pack()
        textoPrograma2= tk.Label(self, text= "El siguiente programa es una DEMO para observar la funcionalidad de los Frames. DEJO ESTO 2 PARA DIFERENCIARLO DEL PRIMER LABEL ").pack()

        botonSiguiente2= tk.Button(self, text= "SIGUIENTE", command=lambda: master.mostrarFrame(frame1))
        botonSiguiente2.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = AppSimple()
    app.mainloop()
```

Básicamente combine los dos módulos en uno.

Lo ideal para mi hubiera sido mantenerlos separados y reitero, no se que tan correcto sea programarlo de esa manera pero me parecía mas fácil.

¡Muchas gracias a todos los que vieron la publicación!

Me temo que el titulo no va tan acorde a la solución que di pero no se como cambiarlo, si alguien lee esto a futuro y no encuentra la resolución a su problema, lo siento muchísimo.

¡Hasta la próxima!

P.D. de hecho hasta la próxima es muy pronto, justo tengo otro problema que les platicare en otra pregunta.